# Sweetalert won't popup in foreach loop table

Tags: php, html, jquery

I want to make the delete button, once clicked, it will popup a modal (sweetalert). I have a few records that I wanted to test deleting it. But the whenever I clicked on "Delete", it will always redirect to the delete.php page without opening the modal first. The table is using foreach loop to display records from database.

Code:

```
<?php 
 if($result)
{foreach($result as $row) {
                                                
?>

    <tr>
        <td class="tb-col" style="width: 15%;"><?php echo $row['admin_id']; ?></td>
        <td class="tb-col">
            <div class="media-group">
                <div class="media-text">
                    <a href="#" class="title"><?php echo $row['admin_fName']." ". $row['admin_lName']; ?></a>
                        <?php echo $row['admin_email']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tb-col"><?php echo $row['admin_username']; ?></td>
        <td class="tb-col">
                                                        
        <?php 
            $registrationDate = $row['registration_date'];

            // Format the date as DD-MM-YYYY
            $formattedDate = date('jS F Y', strtotime($registrationDate));
            echo $formattedDate;
        ?>

        </td>
        
        <td class="tb-col tb-col-end" style="width: 15%;">
            <a href ="delete.php?id=<?= $row['admin_id']; ?>" id="btn-del" class="btn btn-soft btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>

        </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }

        }

        ?>
```

Javascript:

```
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="./assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/data-tables/data-tables.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/sweetalert/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/sweetalert/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-del').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const href = $(this).attr('href');
    
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#2dc58c',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                // Redirect to delete.php if the user confirms
                window.location.href = href;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**What I've tried:**

The modal itself works fine. I have tested it outside of the table and the foreach loop. If it's just one button, it will pop up the modal. The only issue is that, this isn't working on foreach loop table I have created.

Every time I click on Delete and it keeps redirect me to delete.php. My guess, is that the button itself wasn't even captured in the javascript at all.

Code:

```
<div class="nk-block-head-content">
    <ul class="d-flex">
        <li class="d-none d-md-block">
            <a href="./html/delete.php" id="btn-del" class="btn btn-soft btn-primary"><em class="icon ni ni-user"></em><span>Delete</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#btn-del')` will only match one specific element in your page, because in HTML (as in all parts of life), IDs must be unique. That is the whole point of an ID!! But your PHP will generate multiple elements with `id="btn-del"`, which is clearly not valid. jQuery will ignore all the others except the first one it finds, since they are all invalid duplicate IDs (and even if it didn't ignore them, it would have no way of knowing which one you meant). You should bind on a class name instead, since it's permitted for multiple elements to all have the same class (and vice versa).

Comment: Also first time google spider visits your page, it will delete your database since the href will be visited without the "are you sure" popping up. NEVER use an href to manipulate server data!

Comment: ^^^ Agreed. A simple form with a button and a hidden field would be a much safer way of implementing this (and more semantically correct, since you're causing an action rather than fetching data, so a POST would be more appropriate than a GET). P.S. We're not just being paranoid either...what mplugjan describes actually happened to an application I wrote many years ago, when I was young, naive and unaware. It took me a long time to work out why rows of data seemed to be randomly disappearing from the database periodically. So please take it as friendly advice rather than a criticism :-)

Comment: Are you aware of that wrong code? `class="btn btn-soft btn-primary">class="icon ni ni-user">`

Comment: Thank you so much for your input guys. I learned new things here. I didn't know href would lead to google spider to bypass it. I decided to use normal modal instead. It works as intended. I basically just need it to have some kind of warning before deleting records. Turns out, normal modal bootstrap is enough to do the job. I didn't use the href in the button as well.

Comment: Ok good. Yes a search engine spider will follow any `<a href` link it finds on a page automatically - that's a crucial part of how it indexes pages and relates them to each other. So unless this page is secured behind a login screen, a search engine could easily crawl it and visit all the links, assuming they just produce content rather than causing an action such as updating data. By contrast, it will not automatically submit a form or button during the crawling process.

Comment: P.S. I believe you could still use a sweetalert with a button and form, I don't think you actually need to change to a modal in order to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

To apply Sweetalert effect on multiple records (e.g. asking for confirmation before deletion, such as your case), simply use **class** instead of **id**

1. Change `id="btn-del"` to `class="btn-del"`
2. Change `$('#btn-del').on('click',...)` to `$('.btn-del').on('click',...)`

So the code will be (I extracted two records for demonstration) :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tb-col" style="width: 15%;">ID 1</td>
        <td class="tb-col">
            Record 1
        </td>        
        <td class="tb-col tb-col-end" style="width: 15%;">
            <a href ="delete.php?id=1" class="btn-del" class="btn btn-soft btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tb-col" style="width: 15%;">ID 2</td>
        <td class="tb-col">
            Record 2
        </td>
        <td class="tb-col tb-col-end" style="width: 15%;">
            <a href ="delete.php?id=2" class="btn-del" class="btn btn-soft btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
  </table>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.27/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js
"></script>

<link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.27/dist/sweetalert2.min.css
" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-del').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const href = $(this).attr('href');
    
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#2dc58c',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                // Redirect to delete.php if the user confirms
                window.location.href = href;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

You may see the effect thru this [sandbox](https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO5Sept2023.html)

Comment: I've tried using your code, and it's still not popup the modal. I decided to change my coding from using sweetalert and just use normal modal.

Comment: I did check your sandbox, it works. But for some reason it won't work in my foreach loop data tables. I have many records there. If I put the button outside of the foreach loop, it works for only that.